# XPath remove single node (via Saxon CLI)

Tags: xpath, xquery, saxon, xpath-2.0

I want to remove a node from an XML file (using SaxonHE9-8-0-11J):

```
<project name="Build">
  <property name="src" value="src/main/resources" />
  <property name="target" value="target/classes" />

  <condition property="target.exists">
    <available file="target" />
  </condition>
</project>
```

Apparently there are 2 ways I can [do this](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/03/20/xpath2.html).
XPath1: using a not function
XPath2: using an except clause. But both simply return the entire node-set.

With a not function:

```
saxonb-xquery -s:test.xml -qs:'*[not(local-name()="condition")]'
```

With an except clause:

```
saxonb-xquery -s:test.xml -qs:'* except condition'
```

With -explain switch the queries are:

```
<query>
  <body>
    <filterExpression>
      <axis name="child" nodeTest="element()"/>
      <operator op="ne (on empty return true())">
        <functionCall name="local-name">
          <dot/>
        </functionCall>
        <literal value="condition" type="xs:string"/>
      </operator>
    </filterExpression>
  </body>
</query>
```

and

```
<query>
  <body>
    <operator op="except">
      <axis name="child" nodeTest="element()"/>
      <path>
        <root/>
        <axis name="descendant" nodeTest="element(condition, xs:anyType)"/>
      </path>
    </operator>
  </body>
</query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, XPath select nodes from one or more input documents, it doesn't allow you to construct new ones, for that you need XSLT or XQuery. And removing the `condition` child of the `project` root, if that is what you want to achieve, is something you need XSLT or XQuery for, with XPath, even if you use `/*/(* except condition)`, you then get all children except the `condition` element, but as a sequence, not wrapped into a a root.

So with XQuery you could use

```
/*/element {node-name()} { * except condition }
```

as a compact but generic way to reconstruct any root with all child elements except the `condition`: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5b

Whether you get such an expression through a command line shell is a different problem, on Windows with a Powershell window and the cmd shell it works for me to use

```
-qs:"/*/element {node-name()} { * except condition }"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm too exhausted to finish this - I'll have to look at xquery on the weekend. Basically I want to remove a node from a Maven pom.xml and replace the current awk + regex hack. Would be really nice to do it inline.